# Statically link all dependences so that the end user will never be asked to install vc_redist.exe

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, software-distribution, msvcrt

I'm building a Windows executable with VS 2019. When I run it on my machine, it works, but I'm not 100% sure it will work for end users who don't have `vc_redist.x64.exe` version 2019. (Especially users on Win7 - it's in a niche where users still use this version).

How to statically link everything so that the end user will never be asked to download and install Visual C++ Redistributable ["vc_redist"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170)?

I'm using `msbuild.exe`, and no IDE. **Which setting to add in the `.vcxproj` file or in the `.cpp` file to enable full static linking, to prevent the need for vcredist?**

My .cpp code asks for these libraries:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "comctl32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib")
```

Sample .vcxproj:

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="16.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|x64">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>x64</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>    
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.default.props" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ConfigurationType>Application</ConfigurationType>
    <PlatformToolset>v142</PlatformToolset>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props" />
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClCompile Include="main.cpp" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClInclude Include="main.h" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Targets" />
</Project>
```

Note: it is linked with the topic [How to deploy a Win32 API application as an executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16083253/how-to-deploy-a-win32-api-application-as-an-executable), but here it's about doing it specifically directly from the `.vcxproj` file and *without* the IDE.

Comment: you need static link crt libs ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/crt-library-features?view=msvc-170 )

Comment: Thanks @RbMm. There seems to be many lib combinations and many `/MT`, `/MDd`, ... parameters. By the way these are parameters for `cl.exe`, is that right? I don't use `cl.exe` directly, but `msbuild` with a `.vcxproj` file. Where to set all static linking options in a `.vcxproj` file or the `.cpp` file?

Comment: the *cl.exe* used in any case. i be first set this options in vs studio ui and look for generated vcxproj file

Comment: @RbMm I don't use VS IDE / UI, it's not installed, I only have the build tools. Would you have any idea?

Comment: i not use direct vcxproj files (only vs studio). look https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/project-files?view=msvc-170 in <ClCompile> section you need <RuntimeLibrary> parameter. in current example <RuntimeLibrary>MultiThreadedDLL</RuntimeLibrary> but you need instead MultiThreadedDLL - static link (not dll) but i not sure which exactly word need use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a specific ClCompile property for the compilation configuration:

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="16.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    ...
    <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
        <ClCompile>
          <RuntimeLibrary>MultiThreaded</RuntimeLibrary>
        </ClCompile>
    </ItemDefinitionGroup>
</Project>
```

Possible values are here: [runtimeLibraryOption Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.vcprojectengine.runtimelibraryoption)
 (remove the "rt" prefix)

> rtMultiThreaded   0 :  Multi-threaded (/MT)
>
> rtMultiThreadedDebug  1 :  Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)
>
> rtMultiThreadedDebugDLL   3 :  Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd)
>
> rtMultiThreadedDLL    2 :  Multi-threaded DLL (/MD)

More info about MT / MD can be found here: [/MD, /MT, /LD (Use Run-Time Library)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/md-mt-ld-use-run-time-library)

Comment: Thanks! How did you know it's `rtMultiThreaded` and not `rtMultiThreadedDLL`? Is there a doc stating that `rtMultiThreaded` means no use of vc_redist libraries?

Comment: 2/2: if I want to apply this setting to all platforms / all targets, can I do just `<ItemDefinitionGroup><ClCompile><RuntimeLibrary>MultiThreaded` without any `Condition`?

Comment: @Basj - I've not tested, but yes, it should work. The doc is in this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.vcprojectengine.runtimelibraryoption from there you can see MultiThreaded corresponds to /MT documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/md-mt-ld-use-run-time-library